# Advantage of de-duplication of Segments Adobe Analytics

Tags: adobe-analytics

Just wanted to know if there is any advantage of deduplicating segments with same definition in Adobe Analytics?
Can deduplication help in any way?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to multiple segments that have similar definitions, there are a couple advantages:

- **Standardization:** If you have multiple segments with similar or identical names, it'd be pretty easy to have segments with different definitions while sharing the same name. This could lead to inconsistencies in reports.
- **Managability:** If you have multiple segments with the same definition in workspace, it creates unnecessary clutter, making it more difficult to find the segments you're after
- **Performance:** This only applies in extreme cases, but if you have 20,000+ segments in your login company, Analytics can take longer to load. Deduplicating segments would help alleviate that.